# Vertical Navbar (With Hover)

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar, nav

I need help creating a navbar, I've designed it in Photoshop but I'm new to coding and I'm struggling getting exactly what I want.

I've got close, but the code wasn't as simplified as I'd like.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div class="line1">
        <div class="text1">Home</div>
    </div>
    <div class="line2">
        <div class="text2">Work</div>
    </div>
    <div class="line3">
        <div class="text3">About</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#navbar {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    top: 2em;
    right: 3em;
}

.line1 {
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.3;
    height: 3.5em;
    width: 0.2em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.text1 {
    color: white;
    font-family:'Nanum Myeongjo', serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    float: right; 
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
    visibility: visible;
}

.line1:hover > .text1 {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

(I've only shown CSS for 1st nav tab, but 2 and 3 are the same).

This is my design, with Navbar top right:
[image: Example]
https://imgur.com/a/xgmuNAC

https://jsfiddle.net/s6u8gone/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wanting the actual text of the link to only display when hovered over? If so, you were close; but instead of using `visibility:visible;` use `opacity:1;` and then set the text class to have `opacity:0;` as default. As shown:

```
.text1 {
    color: white;
    font-family:'Nanum Myeongjo', serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    float: right; 
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
    opacity:0;
    transition:0.7s ease;
}

.line1:hover > .text1 {
    opacity:1;
    transition:0.7s ease;
}
```

Edit, based off authors comment:

```
.line1:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v14fq6md/

Comment: Yes I am happy with this thanks, however when hovered over the opacity never goes over 0.3, any ideas? - I want the line to be 0.3 and text to be 0 when un-hovered, and then both to 1 when hovered. (Nevermind, I just created an additional hover for just the .line1 and its worked - Thanks a lot).

Comment: I've updated my answer, just need a small line of CSS to apply the `opacity:1;` to the actual line as well as the text